# Font property issue in usercontrol

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a visual basic project builded using Visual Studio 2015. I have make a custom `usercontrol` that contains a `RectangleShape` and a `textbox`. Into `usercontrol` code I have added font properties...

```
Public Overrides Property Font() As Font
    Get
        Return TextBox.Font
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Font)
        TextBox.Font = value
    End Set
End Property
```

So I load my custom `usercontrol` to my project and for example, I change font's size.

[image]

My problem is that I can see the changes into design mode but not into run mode where shows the default font size!!!

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you must do ´TextBox.Invalidate()´ to force the textbox to redraw ? (right after setting the Font value

Comment: @SuperPeanut: Nothing...

Comment: Could you show the code where you change the font value ?

Comment: @SuperPeanut: I don't change the font value using code but from properties explorer!!!

Comment: Can you try to change the font value using code after the call to `InitializeComponents()` ? If that works I think I understand what happens...

Comment: @SuperPeanut: No, nothing...

Comment: It crashes like a ton of bricks.  Get: Return MyBase.Font, Set: MyBase.Font = value: TextBox.Text = value

Comment: @HansPassant: It works!!! Thank you very much my friend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HansPassant** gave the answer to this question!!! So, To help other people who may have the same question, this is how my custom font property should look...

```
Public Overrides Property Font() As Font
    Get
        Return MyBase.Font
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Font)
        MyBase.Font = value
        TextBox.Font = value
    End Set
End Property
```